# Animate an element on a sine path

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

[image: sine wave or curve path for element animation]
I neeed to **move an element on sine wave or path** as shown in  above image. I made something. But it is not working as I want.

```css
img {
  position:absolute;
  animation: roam infinite;
  animation-duration: 15s;
}

@keyframes roam {
  0% { left: 50px; top:100px }
  10%{ left:100px; top:100px }
  20%{ left:200px; top:200px }
  30%{ left:300px; top:50px }
  40%{ left:400px; top:200px }
 
}
```

```html
<img src="https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/idle/idle_simple/sample-128.png">
```

Comment: *this not working as i want.* - Ok but how should it work? You need to clarify what you need and what you mean by curved path.

Comment: yes. wait i am posting an image.

Comment: That's pretty complex (if not impossible) with CSS. You may want to use SVG + CSS animations instead.

Comment: I have an image. I want to move this image. If it's possible with SVG + CSS then Okay. No problem.

Comment: Actually it might not be possible even with SVG. The attribute (`startOffset`) that they are using [in this demo](http://jonibologna.com/svg-text-along-a-path/) seems to have been deprecated.

Comment: no problem. Try if possible in triangular corners path. I think it's possible with @keyframes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can **move an element on a sine path** with 2 *CSS* [keyframe animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes). The point is to translate left right with a linear [timing function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-timing-function) and up/down with an ease-in-out timing function.

This requires to translate the container and move the element up and down **with 2 different keyframe animations**. Here is an example :

```css
div{
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  width:10%;
  animation: translate 15s infinite linear;
}
img {
  position:absolute;
  animation: upDown 1.5s alternate infinite ease-in-out;
  width:100%;
}

@keyframes upDown {
  to { transform: translatey(100px);}
}
@keyframes translate {
  to { transform: translatex(900%);}
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/QdWJXta.png">
</div>
```

Note that this example doesn't contain vendor prefixes. For more info, see canIuse for:

- [CSS keyframe animations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation)
- [CSS 2D transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)

Comment: note 900% of 10% is 90%... 900/100*10/100 = 9 * 0.1 = 0.9 = 90%.... this is why animation knows how far to translate x, how big the page is.